# How to lock any android application

Tags: android

I am a newbie on android apps development, I want to make a application which can lock any application when started. For eg if someone opens chrome or any other application it simply locks it.

Comment: I assume you want the parental control type feature you asked about here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568825/how-to-lock-any-android-application? If so, killing the process as suggested below is not what you want and will potentially result in your users losing data which will result in them removing your app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you will not get any straight forward solution for that.you have to create a service that will run on the background.You can check periodically to find the[running process](http://qtcstation.com/2011/01/getting-info-about-your-currently-running-activities/).Then you can find the package name for the process which you want to kill.Finally use killBackgroundProcess of the ActivityManager to kill the process.This method only kill background process.So if you want to stop browser that starts running simply send that in background(If you bring your activity in foreground it automatically will be back) and run the killBackgroundProcess(pkgName).

Answer (score 0):

[Android now allows users to add app widgets to the lock screen](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#Lockscreen) form API level 17, i dont know backward comparability supports or not